# How to loop through setting different variables to a function's output?

Tags: python, list, pandas, tensorflow

So if I have as shown:

```
x_train = []
y_train = []
x_test = []
y_test = []

for filename in os.listdir('/directory'):
    x_train[os.listdir('/directory').index(filename)], y_train[os.listdir('/directory').index(filename)], x_test[os.listdir('/directory').index(filename)], y_test[os.listdir('/directory').index(filename)] = lstm.format_data(new, seq_len, True)
```

the function format_data() will give multiple indexes to each y_train, x_train, etc and I want to cycle thru these items again when I train my model. I'm using this as a shortcut to writing a ton of this:

```
x_train#, y_train#, x_test#, y_test# = lstm.format_data(.....)
```

Here is the error message I'm getting.

```
IndexError: list assignment index out of range
```

I don't know what the easiest way to do this is and I'm sure many of y'all on here do, so I appreciate all the help I can get!
Thanks

Comment: All of these `os.listdir('/directory').index(filename)` should be replaced with `i` where you loop `for i, filename in enumerate(os.listdir('/directory'))`. Are you asking for a better way to do what you already have, or is there something else?

Comment: @Ry- I get the error above. I'm guessing there's something I'm not doing right with the empty lists

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you're getting the error is that you're trying to give lists an index value instead of assigning them a location in a list.

```
x_train = []
x_train[0] = 'BOB'
```

output

```
IndexError: list assignment index out of range
```

It doesn't work because the list doesn't have a 0th spot already defined.  if you did:

```
x_train = []
x_train.append('BOB')
x_train[0] = 'Mary'
print(x_train)
```

output:

```
['Mary']
```

Then you can assign a value to the 0th spot in the list, because it exists.

This works, if that's what you're looking for:

```
x_train = [None] * 10
x_train[3] = 'Mary'
print(x_train)
```

Output:

```
 [None, None, None, 'Mary', None, None, None, None, None, None]
```

Comment: How am I not doing exactly what your example does in my code? I also changed that line based on what Ry said. now it's `x_train[i], y_train[i], x_test[i], y_test[i] = lstm.format_data(new, seq_len, True)`

Comment: @CarsonP: The example demonstrates the mistake =D You can’t assign to index 3 of a size 0 list.

Comment: Sorry, after reading again I see that sounded kinda hostile. Not my intention at all. So how do I set the original size of the array with I guess blank spaces that I later set to something?

Comment: That could work.  I haven't tested out these other answers with zip and map, but they could work too.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `map` / list comprehension / generator expression and `zip`:

```
>>> import os
>>> import random
>>> 
# some nonsense function for the sake of example
>>> def format_data(filename):
...     return [random.choice(filename) for _ in range(4)]
... 
>>> 
>>> x_train, y_train, x_test, y_test = zip(*map(format_data, os.listdir('.')))
```

This creates four tuples. If it is important they be lists, we  must convert.

```
>>> x_train, y_train, x_test, y_test = map(list, zip(*map(format_data, os.listdir('.'))))
```

Equivalent comprehensions / generator expressions:

```
>>> x_train, y_train, x_test, y_test = zip(*(format_data(fn) for fn in os.listdir('.')))
>>> x_train, y_train, x_test, y_test = (list(x) for x in zip(*(format_data(fn) for fn in os.listdir('.'))))
```

Comment: So with x_train, etc... will they be a list? My function creates I believe a 2 or 3D list so I'm assuming it will become 3 or 4D for each of x_train... That's totally fine I'm just trying to understand how this will work. I need to be able to use those variables again later to fit a model.

Comment: @CarsonP As I said if you use the short version with only `zip` they won't be lists but tuples. The longer version does create lists. How many dimensions depends on the output of `format_data`. Can't you just try the code and see whether you like the result?

Comment: So when I use your code as follows: `x_train, y_train, x_test, y_test = zip(*map(lstm.format_data, os.listdir('/directory'), seq_len, True))` I get this error: `TypeError: argument 3 to map() must support iteration`

Comment: Ok, you need to `from itertools import repeat` and pipe both `seq_len` and `True` through repeat, i.e. `zip(*map(lstm.format_data, os.listdir('/directory'), repeat(seq_len), repeat(True))`